# Find the least natural number such that its cube is less than its factorial.

Tags: factorial, natural-numbers

Basically, find a natural number $k$ such that $k^3 > k!$ but $(k + 1)^3 < (k + 1)!$.
Now I know that the answer is 5.
The issue is in the deriving this through algebra. Here's what I did:

$(k + 1)^3 < (k + 1)!$ $\Rightarrow$ $(k + 1)^3 < k!(k + 1)$ $< k^3(k + 1)$, since $k^3 > k!$, and $(k + 1) > 0$.

Thus, $(k + 1)^3 < k^3(k + 1)$ giving  $(k + 1)^2 < k^3$ because again, $(k + 1) > 0$.

Now the issue is, $k = 6$, for example, satisfies this equation even though its cube is less that its factorial, contrary to the condition this equation was derived using.

I feel I am making some error that is gonna make me pull my hair out once I realise it but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Note that $(k+1)^3<(k+1)!\iff (k+1)^2<k!$ and you can just look at $(k+1)^2<k(k-1)(k-2)$.

Comment: You mean $(k + 1)^2 < k(k - 1)(k - 2)!$ right?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote.  That cubic grows faster than the quadratic, and then you can just check a few cases to confirm.

Comment: But what is the inconsistency in my algebra?

Comment: I couldn't follow what you wrote.  Your implications are only one way so it's hard to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the answer is so low there is no need to do general algebra and inequality manipulation to solve it. We see that $5^3>5!$ and $6^3<6!$, and that's it.

Second, your logic goes the opposite way of what you seem to think. You start with the assumption that $k!<k^3$ and $(k+1)!>(k+1)^3$, and from that derive that $(k+1)^2<k^3$. And this is entirely true. Any $k$ that satisfies $k!<k^3$ and $(k+1)!>(k+1)^3$ will also satisfy $(k+1)^2<k^3$.

However, there are also many other $k$ that satisfy $(k+1)^2<k^3$. This is not a problem. It just means your algebra and inequality manipulation haven't narrowed the set of possible solutions all the way from $\Bbb N$ to a single number. Or, perhaps more correctly, your manipulations have introduced additional solutions.

Comment: What about 0?  Where to the natural numbers begin these days?

Comment: @TerryLoring The natural numbers begin where the context finds them convenient to begin. Ultimately, unless it has been specified, you need to mind read. And I think $0^3<0!$ was not considered by the author of this problem.